# How to deploy own files from maven

Tags: maven, deployment, sakai

I am installing and running sakai project from command prompt
mvn install sakai:deploy
but command prompt show me error that 2 artifact missing that is 2 jar files are missing dwnload it manually 
i am dwnload it and save it in local system then how i can install and deploy it

Comment: Can you add the error log (the relevant part)? Which artifacts are missing? `mvn install sakai:deploy` does not make sense to me. The page [Sakai Maven Builds](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/DOC/Sakai+2.0+Maven+Builds) is pretty old and references Maven 1. Have you read all that? Can you explain in which context you are running the build? Where does the source come from, what steps do you have taken before, ...

Comment: sakai-util:jar:2.6.0 is missing  i am fail to download it manually anyone can provide me the link of jar

Comment: The sakai-util:jar dependency is built when building the rest of the source. It is not downloaded but is a sub project in the overall Sakai build.

Answer (score 2):

When you build Sakai it will generate that missing jar file and place it into the local maven repo. That said, this version of Sakai is very old and you should be running Sakai 10. We suggest you upgrade to Sakai 10 and maven 3. If you do, this issue will go away.

The process for building Sakai is as follows:

1. Open a command line shell
2. Change directory to your Sakai source root directory (should contain many directories including the "master" directory)
3. Execute mvn clean install to build the Sakai source using maven
   Note: The build will take an extra 5-10 minutes to download dependencies the first time
4. Execute mvn sakai:deploy to deploy Sakai to your tomcat using maven

   - Partial builds are supported by the maven2/3 build system
   - You can do a "mvn clean install sakai:deploy" from any subdirectory and build just that code
   - Once you have downloaded the jars you can run maven off-line with mvn -o clean install sakai:deploy

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand you have to manually add the jar in .m2 repository where it needs to be or
add dependency in pom.xml for it(it will automatically add it in repository).
One more thing you can try, go to project>right click>build path> add external jar (it will add the jar to your project).

Comment: There are no maven dependencies in Sakai (as released anyway) which are not included in the maven repositories. There is no need to manually add jars, they will be downloaded as needed.